# Monitor blinks with certain programs

Tags: 12.04, display, xbmc

My computer is a HP dv6 with 8gb ram, 500gb hdd and a amd radeon hd 6480 graphics card and dual core cpu. Now here is my problem:
When I try to run some programs such as gucvie and xbmc, the screen blinks on and off every few. I have tried using both the opensource & proprietary drivers for my graphics card. Running these programs in terminal displays no errors.
Any clues here?

Comment: `the screen blinks on and off every few`... seconds? Or milliseconds? It actually matters (i.e. I'm not just bugging you for the sake of bugging you :P) :)

Comment: It could be switching resolutions.  Have you verified that your programs are using the same resolution that your DE is?